# Parseval Theorem (Rayleigh)

Tags: integration, complex-integration, fourier-transform

I want to solve the following integral: 
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}dt$$

using Parseval Theorem:
$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)g^{*}(x)dx = \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} F(\omega)G^{*}(\omega)d\omega$$

where $F(\omega) = \mathfrak F \{ f(x)\} $

$ G^{*}(\omega)$ is the complex conjugate of the Fourier transform of $g(x)$

I tried to do the following:

$$f(x) = \sin^2 t = \frac{1-\cos 2t}{2} \space ; \space g(x) = t^{-2}$$

However I am only able to obtain :

$$
F(\omega)
   = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2\pi}}
     \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} (1-\cos 2t)e^{i\omega t}dt
$$

My problem is when I am trying to obtain:

$$G(\omega)
   =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
    \int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} t^{-2}e^{i\omega t}dt$$

I think the problem is the discontinuity at $t=0$, but if this is the problem I will alwyas have it since the function to integrate is divided by $t^2$

Anybody knows if the integral can be solved? or if there is a better approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By parts integrating $t^{-2}$ seems to reduce the original integral to $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{2 \sin t \cos t dt}{t} = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\sin(2t) dt}{t}$$ but not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to use that
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{2}e^{ix t} \, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2it} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sin{t}}{t}, $$
so $(\sin{t})/t$ is the Fourier transform of the function $B(x)$ that is $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ on $[-1,1]$ and zero elsewhere.
Then Parseval gives
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin{t}}{t} \right)^2 \, dt = \int_{-1}^{1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \right)^2 \, dx = 2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \pi. $$